# Is it true that there exists idempotents $e,f\in R$ such that $I=Re,J=Rf$ where $ef=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, idempotents

Prove/Disprove:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. In $R$ for any  two distinct  non-trivial ideals $I,J\subseteq R$  we have $(I+J)^2=I+J$.
>   Given ideals $I$ and $J$ in $R$ can we find  idempotents  $e,f\in R$ such that $I=Re,J=Rf$ where  $ef=0$?
>
> An ideal $I$ is said to be non-trivial if $I\neq \{0\},R.$

**MY TRY**:

If I try to prove the fact then let us assume that $I,J$ be two non-trivial ideals in $R$,then $(I+J)^2=I+J$,How should I show that $I=Re,J=Rf$ where $e^2=e;f^2=f;ef=0$??

Comment: The question is ill-posed. You introduce a ring with a property and then you ask something about symbols $I$ and $J$ that are not defined any more. Also, in the property you describe for $R$, you do not exclude the possibility that $I=J$. In this case, even if $I$ is generated by an idempotent, $I=J=Re$ and $e^2=e\ne 0$ because $I$ was assumed nonzero. I feel like you might have misphrased something.

Comment: I don't understand why the question is ill-posed? Why is $I,J$ not defined?@JeskoHüttenhain

Comment: Yes,check the edits @Arthur

Comment: The question is ill posed because logically, there is no connection between the $I$ and $J$ of the two paragraphs. The way the first paragraph is written implies that the letters $I$ and $J$ are dummies used to describe a property of $R$, and that you're done with them the moment that definition is finished. That is why $I$ and $J$ are undefined in the second paragraph.

Comment: No, you've just made the two paragraphs into one. That doesn't change the logic of what's going on. You might as well write "Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. For any  two distinct  non-trivial ideals $I,J\subseteq R$  we have $(I+J)^2=I+J$.
Does there exist idempotents  $e,f\in R$ such that $K=Re,L=Rf$ where  $ef=0$?" You have to tell us what $I$ and $J$ are _in the second sentence as well_, and making that period into a comma is not enough.

Comment: Question Edited;$I,J$ are two given ideals in the ring $R$ in  which the given property holds@Arthur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I misunderstood you question. You want $(I+J)^2=I+J$ for **every** pair of non trivial distinct ideals.

The answer is still **NO**. Take $R=\mathbb{C}^3$. Any ideal of $R$ is the direct product of copies of $(0)$ or $\mathbb{C}$, so $R$ clearly satisfies your assumption.

Take $I=\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}\times (0)$ and $J=\mathbb{C}\times (0)\times (0).$

Then $I=(1,1,0)R$ and $J=(1,0,0)R$.
Notice that the idempotents of $R$ are the vectors whose coordinates are $0$ or $1$. There is only one idempotent generating $I$ , which is $e=(1,1,0)$ and there is only one idempotent generating $J$, which is $f=(1,0,0)$.
Unfortunately $ef\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you the following:

1) Assume that $R$ is a domain. What are the idempotents of $R$ ?

2) Pick your favorite domain $R$ and nontrivial ideals $I,J$ such that $I+J=R.$

3) Conclude.

Comment: Hard to understand your answer!Not sure what you wanted to say at all

Comment: @RishabhPant The answer points to the fact that the answer to your question is *no*. Example: $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $J=3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I said for any two ideals not just a particular one @egreg; take $I=2\Bbb Z,J=4\Bbb Z$

Comment: @RishabhPant Then $I+J=2\mathbb{Z}\ne(I+J)^2=4\mathbb{Z}$. Anyway, a single counterexample disproves a general statement like the one you have in your question, doesn't it?

Comment: I am still unable to understand your point @egreg; I said that for any two distinct ideals $I,J$ we have $(I+J)^2=I+J$ but the hypothesis fails if you take $R=\Bbb Z$

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the question is:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. In $R$ for any two distinct non-trivial ideals $I,J\subseteq R$ we have $(I+J)^2=I+J$.
>   Given ideals $I$ and $J$ in $R$ can we find idempotents $e,f\in R$ such that $I=Re,J=Rf$ where $ef=0$?
>
> An ideal $I$ is said to be non-trivial if $I\neq \{0\},R.$

The answer is no:

Let $R$ be a field.

The condition "for any two distinct non-trivial ideals $I,J\subseteq R$ we have $(I+J)^2=I+J$" is vacuously satisfied be cause there are no non-trivial ideals.

The condition "given ideals $I$ and $J$ in $R$ we can find idempotents $e,f\in R$ such that $I=Re,J=Rf$ where $ef=0$" does not hold because we can set $I=J=(1)$.

Comment: I don't know if you have read the question or have understood the meaning of *non-trivial,proper* or not